# If Statement to change field.control source

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-access

I have a small If statement that that changes the controlsource of a field if another field is empty.  The " just before = is incorrect, and I'm not sure what to use to ensure the entire string starting with the = is included.

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
If IsNull(FirstName2) Then
OwnersNames.ControlSource = "=FirstName1] & " " & [LastName1]"
Else
OwnersNames.ControlSource = "=[FirstName1] & " " & [LastName1] & " and " & [FirstName2] & " " & [LastName2]"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like a couple of syntax hicups

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, then try this which uses more quote marks to concatenate the statement:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
If IsNull(FirstName2) Then
    OwnersNames.ControlSource = "=[FirstName1]" & " " & "[LastName1]"
Else
    OwnersNames.ControlSource = "=[FirstName1]" & " " & "[LastName1]" & " and " & "[FirstName2]" & " " & "[LastName2]"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that and a few other combinations.  with adding the " before the =, I get a "expected end of statement" error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to concatenate the fields (e.g. 'add' them together). You need something like:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    If IsNull(FirstName2) Then
        OwnersNames.ControlSource = "=[FirstName1] & ' ' & [LastName1]"
    Else
        OwnersNames.ControlSource = "=[FirstName1] & ' ' & [LastName1] & ' ' & [FirstName2] & ' ' & [LastName2]"
    End If
End Sub
```

Keep in mind you can concatenate text fields (e.g. text boxes) together.

I'm uncertain if combining the control sources of fields works the same way. To be sure, one option is to rename each textbox to something different from its control source.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, the change you suggested partially works.  When the report is run, only the first portion of the if statement functions.  Essentially, the form just shows the first and last name, even though there is data in the FirstName2 field. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's your if statement. Try doing something like. if me.FirstName2 = vbNullstring then instead. Also try printing out the value of FirstName2 when it's running to trace the issue.

Comment: Ryan, you are correct.  the Me.FristName2 string worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code now, which when loaded produces 'John Smith And' even though the Firstname2 field is null.

```
 Private Sub Report_Load()
 If Me.FirstName2 = vbNullString Then
 OwnersNames.ControlSource = "=[FirstName1] & ' ' & [LastName1]"
 Else
 OwnersNames.ControlSource = "=[FirstName1] & ' ' & [LastName1] & ' and ' & [FirstName2] & ' ' & [LastName2]"

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, for some reason when I add a comment it will not let me cartridge return and add code in, so I have no choice but to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really meaning to set the control source or just the value of the field?
I think this might be what you want to accomplish????

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
 If Me.FirstName2 = "" Then
 me.OwnersNames = [FirstName1] & " " & [LastName1]
 Else
 me.OwnersNames = [FirstName1] & " " & [LastName1] & _  
" and " & [FirstName2] & " " & [LastName2]

End If
End Sub
```